# Fork Join simple program example - need guidance on error

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a small program based on my understanding of ForkJoinPool executor service in java. The output of the program is not as desired.

My understanding:- My understanding of the ForkJoinPool is that it is another flavour of executor service with work stealing feature which makes a thread steal a work from another's queue if it is done with all it's jobs or has become idle. This increases the usage of cpu by threads.
Forking is used to split a bigger task to a smaller one till the time a task is simple enough to be executed sequentially.
Joining joins the two divided tasks to perform an operation if needed.

My examples:- Based on the above understanding, I tried to create a program. The task is that a Parson object's run method is to be called. There are four person objects in array. I want four threads to work in parallel on all these Person objects, which means in an array of four objects my base condition is array,0,0.

Output expected:- Incompute(not sure how many times)
Hello (4 times)
Thread Id (4 times)
Output actually coming - In Compute being printed many a times and hello none of the time. The output is not fixed, it varies.

Could someone guide me on the mistake I am making ?

```
package com.gc;

import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class FJMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Person p1 = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();
    Person p3 = new Person();
    Person p4 = new Person();

    Person[] array = new Person[4];
    array[0] = p1;
    array[1] = p2;
    array[2] = p3;
    array[3] = p4;

    FJMain.MyRecursiveAction action =  new FJMain().new MyRecursiveAction(array,0,3);

    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
    pool.invoke(action);

}

private class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction{

    private Person[] array;
    private int start;
    private int end;


    public MyRecursiveAction(Person[] array,int start,int end){
        this.array = array;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In compute");
        int mid = (this.start + this.end)/ 2;
        if(mid < 1){
            computeDirectly(array,mid);
        }else{
            MyRecursiveAction subTask1 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, start, mid);
            subTask1.fork();
            MyRecursiveAction subTask2 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, mid + 1, end);
            subTask2.fork();
        }
    }

    private void computeDirectly(Person [] array,int end){
        for(Person p:array){
            p.name();
        }
    }

}

}


package com.gc;

public class Person {

public void name(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
}

}
```

**EDIT**

```
int beg = this.start;
        int last = this.end;
        int mid = (this.start + this.end)/ 2;
        if((last - beg) < 1){
            computeDirectly(array,beg);
        }else{
            MyRecursiveAction subTask1 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, start, mid);
            subTask1.fork();
            MyRecursiveAction subTask2 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, mid + 1, end);
            subTask2.fork();
        }
```

Comment: Please explain why you expect to see `Hello` and the thread id 4 times.

Comment: Also, what is the behavior of `int mid = (this.start + this.end) / 2;` for the right child of your fork?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Thanks for replying, I expect to see hello four times because my base case is an array with just one person object and in totality there are four person objects. I have seen you reply below, give me sometime, I will analyze your suggestion and work that out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecursiveAction` creates recursive tasks that do not terminate.

```
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 0, 3);
```

creates

```
mid = (0 + 3) / 2 = 1
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 0, 1);
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 2, 3);
```

which create

```
mid = (0 + 1) / 2 = 0
completes

mid = (2 + 3) / 2 = 2
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 2, 2);
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 3, 3);
```

which create

```
mid = (2 + 2) / 2 = 2
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 2, 2);
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 3, 2);

mid = (3 + 3) / 2 = 3
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 3, 3);
new MyRecursiveAction(array, 4, 3);
```

ad nauseam. Some of these will `computeDirectly` but most will not as they degenerate.

You'll have to fix your base case and the way you recur.

Comment: I have modified the base condition and the program output is still unpredictable, to me the base condition looks fine. I am pasting an edit in the code. The number of times Hello is printed is varying.

Comment: If you print out the value of start, mid, and end in each `compute` call, you'll see where it starts degenerating.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is printing "inCompute". Take that out and the program works fine. System.out is shared, you never know the exact order of printing.

How the F/J program manipulates tasks is internal to that program. Take a look at the source; that is enough to scare anyone. Each call to compute sends a string to system.out whether it is splitting or doing computeDirectly().

**Edit1:**

This output is Hello/n 12/n four times. The 12 is the thread id which is the same. This tells me that the splitting thread is picking up the new tasks from it's own deque and processing them before the other threads get a chance to participate. Since you're only using an array of four, this makes sense.

Try using an array of 4 million. F/J is not meant to run on such small input. There is no point in parallelizing such a small input.

If you are not getting the same results, then there is another issue with your environment.

Comment: @edharned- Thanks for replying, give me sometime to analyze your answer and I will come back to you.

Comment: I have removed the "inCompute" system print and made a change to my base condition but the output is still unpredictable, the number of times hello is printed is varying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a better job at learning how to debug a program.  Why doesn't it complete?  Why don't you see the four "Hello"'s like you expect? Where should you first look?

Well, is `computeDirectly` ever being hit? Not really, why?  First find out why `computeDirectly` isn't being hit.  What is the smallest value `mid` can be?  If you actually printed out the values or debugged the smallest value `mid` can be you'll notice it will be `1`.

If you change the conditional where you computeDirectly to

```
if (mid <= 1) {
     computeDirectly(array, mid);
}
```

You'll see your expected results.

It will always be `1` because `0 + 3 / 2` is 1 and cannot decompose any further than than.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. It seems like the edited base condition in my question looked fine. I tried to change the else condition and used the code at

http://rashidnoorani.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-use-fork-join-framework-features.html

I still trying to find out the root cause, may take some time. I will reply back on this post. Here is the changed code and I can see Hello being printed 4 times consistently.

```
@Override
        protected void compute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int beg = this.start;
            int last = this.end;
            int mid = (this.start + this.end)/ 2;
            System.out.println(this.start +" " +mid + " "+this.end);

            if((last - beg) < 1){
                computeDirectly(array,beg);
            }else{
                /*MyRecursiveAction subTask1 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, start, mid);
                subTask1.fork();
                MyRecursiveAction subTask2 = new MyRecursiveAction(array, mid + 1, end);
                subTask2.fork();*/
                invokeAll(new MyRecursiveAction(array, start, mid), new MyRecursiveAction(array, mid + 1, end));
            }
```